# how to use subsonic generated files?

Tags: subsonic

I have Visual 2010, I am trying to generate dal from my database.

1. I create a classlibrary project
2. I add reference to Subsonic
3. I add reference to mysql
4. create generated file in directory
5. I add a App.config file and fill it as this:

I create the external tools button and run it, 
it generates the CS files, but doesnt appear in generate files,

what to do next to use these files in my application??

thanks

Comment: <configSections>
    <section type="SubSonic.SubSonicSection, SubSonic" name="SubSonicService" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="test"  connectionString="Server=localhost;User ID=root;Password=;Database=test;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <SubSonicService defaultProvider="test">
    <providers>
      <add type="SubSonic.MySqlDataProvider, SubSonic" name="test" generatedNamespace="test"  connectionStringName="test"   />
    </providers>
  </SubSonicService>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the generated files into your Visual Studio project.  Find the folder with the files and drag them into your project.